# Simple vue example render to dom

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello all and thank you very much.

This is my first try with vue.js and I cant get the example working.

this is the error i am getting

> vue.runtime.esm.js:620 [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

What does compile mean? It's seems like a valid ES5. I am using the `rollup-plugin-vue`here. What option should I use to get the compiled components. or am I trying to connect to the DOM incorrectly?

Thank you very much :)

```js
    var ListItem = Vue.component('ListItem', {
      data: function () {
        return {
          title: ''
        }
      },
      addNewItem: function() {
        if(this.newItem.trim().length > 0) {
            this.items.push(this.newItem);
            this.newItem = "";
        }
      },
      template:  `
        <div class="list-item">
          {{ title }}
        </div>
      `
    });
    var DynamicList = Vue.component('DynamicList', {
      data: function () {
        return {
          title: '',
          newItem: '',
          items: []
        }
      },
      addNewItem: function() {
        if(this.newItem.trim().length > 0) {
            this.items.push(this.newItem);
            this.newItem = "";
        }
      },
      template: `
        <div class="dynamic-list">
          <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
          <div>
            <input type="text" v-model="newItem">
            <input type="button" >
          </div>
          <ListItem
            v-for="item in items"
            v-bind:key="item"
            v-bind:title="title"
          ></ListItem>
        </div>
      `
    });


    new Vue({
        el: "#vue-container",
        data: {},
        render: h => h(DynamicList),
    });
```

Comment: from a google, does this help? https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler

Comment: Also, more specifically this page: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only but in order to give you an answer it would be useful to know how are you including Vue? Are you using a link to a script file on a CDN or are you using Webpack? If webpack, please post your package.json as you may be including the wrong vue assets.

Comment: thanks ``new Vue({
runtimeCompiler: true, 
        render: DynamicList
    }).$mount("#container")``  now giving  ``typeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined``

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds